# Specifying resource qualifier

Tags: android

My app is being developed for a region where most users have English as the default language. However, the app allows a user to choose the a local language. Since the user will not be setting the device's overall language, the default string resources will be called. Is it possible to get a resource from a  specific qualifier e.g. values-myQualifier/strings.xml?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to set diffrent locale for application you can use following code:

```
Locale locale = new Locale(countyCode);
Locale.setDefault(locale);
Configuration config = new Configuration();
config.locale = locale;
getBaseContext().getResources().updateConfiguration(config,
        getBaseContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics()); 
onCreate(null);
```

Check also [ResourceBundle](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/ResourceBundle.html)